# Mejorar visualización 3D de un valle

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, visualización-de-datos

Estoy intentando hacer una buena visualización de un valle/terreno, cuyas coordenadas están dadas por las variables x,y,z, sin embargo he tenido algunos problemas con la barra de colores, pues esta me queda superpuesta con el rótulo del eje Z. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo arreglar este problema? También, si pueden recomendarme una mejor opción para visualizar los datos, lo agradecería muchísimo, ya que la imagen que tengo presenta mucha pixelación. Esta es la imagen que de momento saca mi programa:

[image: Imagen de cómo se ve mi visualización]

Y este es el código... Este simplemente toma datos de una malla que contiene información de los puntos (pts) y los elementos cuadriláteros (quads). A partir de esto puedo obtener las coordenadas x,y,z de cada punto que conforman al terreno, simplemente diciendo que x =pts[:,0], y =pts[:,1] y z =pts[:,2].

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    from matplotlib import cm
    pts = np.loadtxt("valle_aburra-quads.pts")/1000
    quads = np.loadtxt("valle_aburra-quads.quad",dtype=np.int)
    
    A = np.zeros((4, 2))
    wi= 1 ##Peso  
    r = 1/np.sqrt(3) #punto de cuadratura r 
    s = 1/np.sqrt(3) #punto de cuadratura s
    
    
    
    N0 = (1/4)*(1-r)*(1-s) #interpolador del nodo 0
    N1 = (1/4)*(1+r)*(1-s) #interpolador del nodo 1
    N2 = (1/4)*(1+r)*(1+s) #interpolador del nodo 2
    N3 = (1/4)*(1-r)*(1+s) #interpolador del nodo 3
    N_trans = np.array([N0, N1, N2, N3])  #Matriz de interpolación
    D_trans = np.array([[0.25*(s-1), 0.25*(-s+1), 0.25*(s+1), 0.25*(-s-1)],[0.25*(r-1), 0.25*(-r-1), 0.25*(r+1), 0.25*(-r+1)]])
    
    
    Vol_valle = 0 #Inicializa el volumen de cero
    Area_valle = 0 #Inicializa el área de cero
    
    #for i in range(len(quads)):
    
    for i in range(len(quads)):
        for j in range (0, 4):
            for k in range (0,2):
                
                A[j,k] = pts[quads[i,j],k]
                
        B = np.dot(N_trans, A)  #Producto entre la matriz 
          
        Ja = np.dot(D_trans, A[:,:]) #Jacobiano
        
        Area = 4*np.linalg.det(Ja)
    
        Area_valle = Area_valle + Area #Suma el área de todos los cuadriláteros
        
        #Determina la altura z mínima 
        z_min = np.amin(pts[:,2])
        #Saca el promedio de las alturas
        z_mean = pts[:,2].mean() - z_min
        #Determina el volumen de cada uno de los cuadriláteros haciendo la multiplicación del área por la altura
        Vol_valle = Area_valle*(z_mean)
    
    #Realiza el plot de los puntos para visualizar el valle
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    
    x =pts[:,0]
    y =pts[:,1]
    z =pts[:,2]
    
    #ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='g', marker='o',)
    surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=2, antialiased=False, shade=False)
    #surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap='CMRmap', linewidth=2, antialiased=False)
    ax.set_xlabel('Eje x [m]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Eje y [m]')
    ax.set_zlabel('Eje z [m]')
    
    
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.7, aspect=13)
    
    
    plt.show()
```

Aquí se encuentran los archivos .quad y .pts necesarios para correr el programa: https://we.tl/t-aVEhveTL7e

Comment: Tienes que poner aquí el código relevante al problema. El sitio que referencias es "poco amigable": necesita Javascript y pide aceptar cookies. También muestra el gráfico que mencionas.

Comment: Prueba con `fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.7, aspect=13,pad=0.15)` para poner algo de distancia entre ejes y barra de color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambos problemas (barra muy pegada al eje y figura demasiado pixelada) son efectos secundarios de tener una figura demasiado pequeña.

Si cambias el tamaño de la figura para que sea mayor, lograrás dar más espacio a matplotlib para que separe correctamente la barra de colores de la leyenda. Además la imagen PNG resultante tendrá muchos más pixeles, y por tanto mejor resolución.

Por ejemplo, simplemente añadiendo a tu código esta línea antes del `fig.show()`:

```
fig.set_size_inches(20, 15)
```

el resultado pasa a ser el siguiente:

[image: Resultado]

También, puedes guardar la figura en un formato vectorial, para que la resolución sea siempre la máxima posible aún si alguien quiere examinarla con detalle y haciendo zoom. Por ejemplo, puedes guardarla como pdf:

```
fig.savefig("figura.pdf")
```

Cuidado! el pdf resultante puede ser pesado y tardar mucho en visualizarse, pues contiene básicamente las órdenes para volver a dibujar la figura, a la resolución que sea.

Si por ejemplo se hace zoom sobre una zona del PNG, se harán visibles los pixels:

[image: PNG pixelado]

Sin embargo un zoom sobre el PDF se ve siempre perfecto (aunque, insisto, puede tardar en redibujarse y ser pesado para la máquina):

[image: PDF perfecto]

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Muchísimas gracias, me sirvió mucho.